# Replacing string value in Python list with specific number value

Tags: python

I want to replace string value in Python list with specific number value.
For example if I have list:

```
l = ["orange", "lemon", "apple", "orange", "apple","orange", "lemon","lemon", "apple", "grape", "grape", "lemon", "grape"]
```

I want to get:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4]
```

I know that this can be done with `pandas` and `map` function. But what if I have 50 different categories? It would be stupid to write different case for each category? Is there a way to do this automatically?

Comment: What have you tried yourself? What problem did you run into? Also, what is the realistic size of the actual data - you mention 50 categories, but how many elements are there in the list you're looking to process?

Comment: List can have more than 50 different categories and each category can occur from 5 to 30 times

Comment: What is your intention with the mapping? Is it to map the nth (1-indexed) distinct value in the list `l` to the integer `n`? Or is it a more generic map, for example you decide ahead of time that "orange" should be mapped to 7?

Comment: I want to convert categorical data to numeric data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably impractical, but you can use the id of each string:

```
l = ["orange", "lemon", "apple", "orange", "apple"]
l2 = [id(s) for s in l]
print(l2)
```

Output:

```
[2379879963760, 2379879963504, 2379877859760, 2379879963760, 2379877859760]
```

Every unique string will have a unique id.

Answer (score 1):

This can simply be accomplished with a list comprehension without using Pandas:

```
>>> [l.index(i) + 1 for i in l]
[1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 10, 10, 2, 10]
```

Note that each value in the result is unique for a given string.

Update: If you want to have the exact output in your question, it's a bit more complicated. Since Python does not have a built-in `OrderedSet`, you can use `OrderedDict` to imitate it and extract the unique values in order:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> unique_elements = OrderedDict(zip(l, range(len(l))))
>>> d = dict(zip(unique_elements, range(1, 1 + len(unique_elements))))
>>> [d[i] for i in l]
[1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4]
```

Comment: this does not work, it does not give proper results. I have added bigger list, so please check it

Comment: @taga True, I had assumed that any unique ID is fine for your purposes. Updated my answer.

Comment: @taga I am now confused with your accepted answer. What was wrong with my original answer then?